# Adding SSI support causes mod_dir "trailing slash" redirect to stop working

Tags: .htaccess, server-side-includes, apache-2.2

I have enabled SSI using the following directives in .htaccess

```
AddHandler server-parsed .html
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES html
```

However when I add these, the trailing slash redirects stop working.

For eg. http://testwp.humbug.in/test/index.html works fine

but

http://testwp.humbug.in/test/ doesn't work.

In chrome it gives a "Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)" error while in firefox it shows a blank page.

What additional configuration do I need for both mod_dir and mod_include to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer on the dreamhost forums:

> Try specifying the RemoveOutputFilter
>   directive first? I'm thinking the
>   problem might be output having gone
>   through DEFLATE (gzip) already.

http://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-130315.html

So added

```
RemoveOutputFilter html
```

before AddOutputFilter and that worked like a charm